# jSoup - Is it possible to match elements with a minimum attr() length?

Tags: java, coldfusion, jsoup, railo

I can match elements in jSoup very easily, but then, after the fact, I need to check these values to see if they are at least longer than 1 character.

I was wondering if there was a way to match elements with a specific attribute, but only if that attribute's content length is longer than 1 character?

Hopefully this would then allow me to not have to manually check the lengths myself.

```
document.select("img[src]")
```

The above matches all `img` tags with the `src` attribute, but some attributes may be blank and I'd rather not have them match at all.

Pseudo code explaining what I mean:

```
document.select("img[src:length(1)]")
```

I have looked through the reference, but cannot find anything suitable - except perhaps a RegEx solution?

http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html

Thanks,
Mikey.

Comment: Why has my tag been changed to 'JavaScript'? This is not JavaScript, it is Java. jSoup is a Java library that uses CSS style syntax.

Answer (score 1):

> [attr~=regex] elements with an attribute named "attr", and value matching the regular expression

Based on this from the source link you provided, you could do something like this

```
document.select("img[src~=.+]");
```

This should result in a selection of img elements with a src attribute of one character or more.

Comment: The doc suggests it's only a partial match, so can use `.` instead of `.+` and still game the same results.

Answer (score -3):

In javascript, length is a property.  To see if it's greater than 1, do this

```
if ( document.select("img[src]").length > 1 )
do something
else
do something else
```

You just have to decide when and where to apply that logic.

Comment: This is not JavaScript...it is Java. I am using jSoup which is a Java HTML parser.